# How to make the live editor for WordPress plugin setting page?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am author of the WordPress plugin [Tipu Scroll To Top](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tipu-scroll-to-top/). Can anyone please that how can I allow users to see the live changes on the setting page. Currently, I am using the jQuery for only the scroll to top button and it is as below

```
(function($){
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $('#stt_container') .fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('#stt_container') .fadeIn();
    }
});
$('#stt_container').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
    });
```

})( jQuery );

Comment: what do you mean by "to see the live changes on the setting page" ?

Comment: Actually, I want to make a live editor in the admin . So, the users will see the changes before saving the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Eager: https://eager.io/developer/features

You can create an Eager plugin, and then export it as a Wordpress plugin which will support live preview: https://eager.io/developer/cms

You can try out an example plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/drift-by-eager/

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.